# How can I make this Ruby method more beautiful?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I believe that the conditions can be written better:

```
def update
  if allow_update?
    if @company.update_attributes(params[:company])
      flash.now[:success] = "success message"
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "error message"
    end
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "error message"
  end

  render :show
end
```

How can I rewrite this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the `&&` operator, two `if`s can be merged to one:

```
def update
  if allow_update? && @company.update_attributes(params[:company])
    flash.now[:success] = "success message"
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "error message"
  end

  render :show
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some string interpolation and ternary operators for shortening the code.

```
def update
  allow_update? && @company.update_attributes(params[:company]) ? result = "success" : 
  result = "error"
  flash.now[result.to_sym] = "#{result} messege"
  render :show
end
```